# Is String prefered over StringBuilder in IntelliJ Idea (JPA)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm trying Idea as my new IDE (used Eclipse so far), so sorry for a newbie question maybe.

I just found, that when my JPA query is written as String

```
String query = 
    "Select p" +
    "  from Person p ";
```

Idea is performing highlighting navigation (when clicked with CTRL on Person), while for basically same thing using StringBuilder it fails

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
query.append("Select p");
query.append("  from Person p ");
```

So my question is basically, whether I can achieve the same with StringBuilder...

My motivation for StringBuilder is mainly code formatting, because in case of String it would be very likely changed to one liner if someone else in my team triggers code formatting in Eclipse... (I have no experience with code formatting in Idea, I mean I do not know what to expect, while I know quite good what to expect from Eclipse).

To be fair to Idea, Eclipse is not doing any of those advanced features (one of the reasons/motivations to move to Idea)...

Comment: whether StringBuilder is preferred over a String concatenation depends on the use case, not on the IDE you use

Comment: Is there an injected language/reference active in the stringbuilder case? If not, please add one and update your post to indicate whether or not it helps. From a language perspective this is a nitpick since concatenation of string literals is done at compile time anyway.

Comment: @Stultuske I believe I clearly described what is the difference using String and StringBuilder in Idea. Functionality in example I provided is exactly the same...

Comment: In my idea, neither example lets me ctrl-click on "Person". Also, autoformat does not change eiither example in my editor. I would use String, it's easier to read.

Comment: @AndreyAkhmetov well, it's not showing anywhere I looked, but assuming from tha fact I could add it it was not. When I added it, I'm getting warning like " from expected" in first line and "from unexpected" on a second line...

Comment: @Christine might depend on project facets I have JPA in facets...

Comment: In that case the IDE likely lacks logic to concatenate injected language snippets across stringbuilder calls. Have you actually checked to see if auto format will tamper with your original string concatenation? On my copy of IDEA 2018.2 the concatenation is preserved as is.

Comment: @AndreyAkhmetov by "in case of String it would be very likely changed to one liner" I meant some of my team mates using Eclipse still, but I see it was not clear...

Comment: In your example, using StringBuilder is worse, because `"Select p" + "  from Person p "` is *exactly the same* as writing `"Select p  from Person p "`.  Concatenation of constants is done at compile time, not at runtime.  The compiled .class file will contain one String constant, not two.

Comment: @VGR his motivation is basically for formatting purposes. And that's why externalizing them is better.

Comment: @VGR this is simplified example, typically queries consist of several joins sometimes with non-trivial conditions (where), so I definitely do not like to have one long line...

Comment: @Betlista It’s perfectly fine to split a long String into multiple lines using `+`.  I do it all the time.  My point is that using StringBuilder will be slower, and harder to read.

Comment: I believe, that String concatenation is changed by compiler to `append`, so speed gain is questionable and it's very small anyway. From my point of view as both cases are aligned properly, readability is the same, that's also why I used `query.append` on second line, while just `.append` would be fine, but it won't be aligned properly in Eclipse...

Comment: @Betlista when I was building a framework over JTOpen for IBMi, every command I had to issue on the host machine was constructed using StringBuilder. **Never did that again**. I realized it was a mess only at the end

Answer (score 2):

Edit: there are also

```
// @formatter:off
  ... code ...
// @formatter:on
```

Which, however, works only on IDEA, as far as I know.

---

Suggestion, a bit outside of the scope of this question.
Use *property files* (or whatever document type) to contain SQL statements. Externalize them.

e.g.:

```
my-statement=\
   select field1, field2, field3 \ 
   from mytable \
   where field4 = '...' and \
         field5 = '...'
```

On the long run this will be **a lot** easier to maintain.
IDEA will provide language injection both for SQL and for JPQL.

[image]

Comment: Well I tried and the outcome is very similar to `StringBuilder` - warning "',' or from expected" on first line and also navigation to Person not working in property file same as no completion on `es.`

Comment: @Betlista for completion you need to better configure your DataSource. But it works fine as I use it regularly. My experience is mostly pure SQL however Btw, did you inject JPA QL?

Comment: @Betlista alternatively you can consider using the "formatter" tags, as above.